# Similar Grouping in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two for loops in vba that are iterating over column b and checking to see if the first word in the current cell is the same as the first word in any other cell and if so copying them into another column, therefore grouping similar items.  But, when I go to copy and paste the matches it finds, it only copy and pastes the matches, not the original cells that it is comparing against.  I would like to have the matches and the original cells as well in the grouping but I am unsure where to modify my code so it will do so.  I am rather new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub FuzzySearch()

Dim WrdArray1() As String, WrdArray2() As String, i As Long, Count As Long, Rng1 As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet, positionx As Long, positiony As Long
Dim rng2 As Range

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With WS
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
With Columns("B")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas).Activate
End With

position = 1

For j = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count

WrdArray1 = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate
WrdArray2 = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")

If UBound(WrdArray2) < 0 Then

    End
End If

If WrdArray1(0) = WrdArray2(0) Then
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("C" & position)
    position = position + 1
    Count = Count + 1
End If

Next j

Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a mixture of arrays and Ranges it would probably be easier and less confusing to populate one of the arrays with the final output (including the comparator) within a loop and then transfer the array to the worksheet in a single command.

However, perhaps consider the following approach which lets Excel do all the 'heavy lifting'.  It's the same number of code lines but I have annotated it for your information.  This illustrates the filling of an array in a loop and transferring it to a Range.  Change the various variables to suit your situation.

```
Sub grpAndCount()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strow As Long, endrow As Long, stcol As Long
Dim coloffset As Long, r As Long
Dim newstr As String
Dim drng As Range
Dim strArr() As String

'Data start r/c
strow = 6   'Row 6
stcol = 2   'Col B

'Offset no of Cols from Data to place results
coloffset = 2

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        'find last data row
        endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, stcol).End(xlUp).Row

            'for each data row
            For r = strow To endrow
                'get first word
                newstr = Left(.Cells(r, stcol), InStr(.Cells(r, stcol), " ")-1)
                'put string into array
                ReDim Preserve strArr(r - strow)
                strArr(r - strow) = newstr
            Next r

        'put array to worksheet
        Set drng = .Range(.Cells(strow, stcol + coloffset), .Cells(endrow, stcol + coloffset))
        drng = Application.Transpose(strArr)

        'sort newly copied range
        drng.Sort Key1:=.Cells(strow, stcol + coloffset), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

        'provide a header row for SubTotal
        .Cells(strow - 1, stcol + coloffset) = "Header"

        'resize range to include header
        drng.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(drng.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Select

        'apply Excel SubTotal function
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlCount, Totallist:=Array(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'remove 'Header' legend
        .Cells(strow - 1, stcol + coloffset) = ""
    End With

End Sub
```